# Matching the size of the flattened convolution layer with the 1st FC layer size

Tags: neural-networks

Suppose that the size of the last convolution layer or max pooling layer in a neural network was NxNxM. What would be the size of the corresponding flattened layer? I thought it would be, well, 1x1x(N*N*M).

Looking at the [VGG16 network](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/VGG16-architecture-16_fig2_321829624), and I'm a bit confused now. The last max pooling layer of VGG16 is 7x7x512, but the drawing seems to indicate that the flattened layer is 1x1x4096.

Maybe I misread the drawing, maybe the flattened layer is 1x1x(7*7*512)=1x1x25088, and 1x1x4096 is the 1st FC layer? I doubt that: full connectivity from 25088 to 4096 neurons would require 102760448 weights (not including bias).

Could you clarify for me what I'm seeing wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawing doesn't include the flattening operation. The first FC layer has 4096 units, and as you calculated the layer before it has an output size of 7 x 7 x 512 = 25,088 units, so that would require just over 100 million weights between the flattened output of the last max-pooling layer and the first FC layer.

Can this be possible? In the original [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf) introducing VGG16, they mention a total number of parameters around 140 million (see their Table 2). By my calculation, all the conv layers together use around 15 million parameters. The last two FC layers contribute around 20 million more parameters (4096 x 4096 + 4096 x 1000), so that leaves just over 100 million, which corresponds exactly to the number of parameters we calculated for the first FC layer.